# Point to point path in a Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, path, shortest

I want an algorithm to be able to find an optimal path between two vertices on a graph (with positive int weights).The thing is my graph is relatively big (up to 100 vertices). I have considered the dijkstra algorithm but as I searched  the net most implementions use the adjacency matrix which in my case will be 100x100.

If you could recommend me a certain source to read and learn from , or even better provide me with a c++ implementaion it will be great.

PS: The algorithm needs to output the required route and not just the shortest distance between two points.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) - it takes the best from dijkstra and greedy algorithms and is used in lots of video games. Here comes C++ implementation: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577457-a-star-shortest-path-algorithm/

Comment: Ok , I will give it ago , I found an implementaion along with a tutorial.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm)?

Here's a good article to start reading: http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html

Comment: I have implemented the A* algorithm using the pseudocode provided by wikipedia .It seems to work fine but I can't understand one small part in the pseudocode to be more specific I cant understand what the reconsruct function does . What is the total_path, an array? If you could explain this particular function a bit it would be great.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)